# When the screen turns Off, the countdowntimer doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a class which extends a CountDownTimer and it works good, but when the screen is turned Off, the timer is desynchronized, so the idea is that, when I get out of the activity or the screen is Off, the CountDownTimer should be continue working properly. I have the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`, also I have tried with `PowerManager`, but I think the problem is not there.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService((MenuApp.this).POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
       wl.acquire();
       myTimer =  new CustomTimer(min, 1000); 
       myTimer.start();                    
       wl.release();
```

.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class CustomTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
    public CustomTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {

        super( millisInFuture, countDownInterval );
        byteTimer = 1;
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) 
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public synchronized void onTick(long millisUntilDone) 
    {
   String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d", 
           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilDone)- TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilDone)),
           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilDone)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilDone)));

                 tim.setText(hms);
                 edit.putLong("Minute",  millisUntilDone-1669);
                 edit.commit();

    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) 
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public synchronized void onFinish() 
    {   
        tim.setText("00:00");
                seconds = 0L;
                if(btnToggle.isChecked()){   
                        btnToggle.setChecked(false);
                        btnToggleTimer.setChecked(false);                   
                    }else{
                        btnToggle.setChecked(true);
                        btnToggleTimer.setChecked(false);
            }         
        }
    }
```

Comment: "also I have tried with PowerManager, but I think the problem is not there" -- yes, it is. You have arranged to keep the device awake long enough to create an instance of `CustomTimer` and call `start()` on it. Then the device can go back to sleep.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, What do you recommend me to do? I mean the timer is working, but If I get out of the activity, doesn´t stop for 5 minutes, it stops for 5 minutes and 20 seconds.

Comment: @Soyer Hey I'm having a similar issue; what did you end up doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you recommend me to do?

The clunky answer is to do what you tried to do: keep the CPU on all the time. You would `acquire()` the `WakeLock` before you start the timer and only `release()` it when you stop the timer. However, users will want to do nasty things to you with pointy sticks if you keep the CPU on all the time during the countdown, as that drains the battery. It also may be tricky to not screw up and leak the `WakeLock`, forgetting to `release()` it in some scenario, causing the CPU to remain on so long as your process continues running. That might be enough to cause users to come after you with heavier weaponry.

Hence, don't use `CountDownTimer`. Instead, use `AlarmManager` (to get control when the countdown is over, even if the device is asleep) and something lightweight (e.g., a `postDelayed()` loop) to keep updating the UI while you happen to be in the foreground. This will minimize the battery drain while still giving you control at the right time.

Comment: Using setInexactRepeating() in alarmManager will work in Doze mode also?

Comment: @kavie: It will subject to standard Doze limitations. So, it will work, but when the device is in Doze mode, the alarms will become much less frequent.

Comment: I need to trigger alarm every 10 seconds in android wear app.till 2 minutes.Problem here is by default alarm is automatically increasing time to 60 seconds.

Comment: @kavie: Then you would need to use the approach from the first paragraph of my answer.